# Problem when using appendchild to show multiple div objects

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm having an issue regarding on showing multiple barcodes inside HTML page for printing. the barcode is OK, the html div is ok, but when i run the script, i dont know why, the way that i managed to get it done in the for loop below is printing more stuff than expected, as you can check below:

```
            if (imprimirQuantidadeTotal == true) {

                for (var i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
                    container.appendChild(etiqueta);
                    container.innerHTML += etiqueta;
                }
            }
```

I removed some not important variables for now, but this is the whole page. no CSS necessary for now.

```
 <body>
        <div class="container" style="display: flex; flex-direction:column; flex-wrap:wrap;">
            <div class="etiqueta">
                <svg class="barcode"></svg>
                <div style="display:inline;">
                    <span id="pedido"></span>
                    <span id="item"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="~/Scripts/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var quantidade = 3; //receber quantidade na modal
            var imprimirQuantidadeTotal = true; //checkbox?
            var elements = null;
            var etiqueta = document.querySelector(".etiqueta");
            var container = document.querySelector(".container");

            if (pedido != null) {
                document.querySelector('#pedido').textContent = pedido.toUpperCase()
            }
            if (item != null) {
                document.querySelector('#item').textContent = item.toUpperCase()
            }

            if (imprimirQuantidadeTotal == true) {

                for (var i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
                    container.appendChild(etiqueta);
                    container.innerHTML += etiqueta;
                }
            }

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                JsBarcode(".barcode", numero, {
                    format: "CODE128",
                    width: 1,
                    height: 50
                })
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

And here it is the output:
[Output to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kLsN.png)

Comment: Why are you doing `container.innerHTML += etiqueta;`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? You mention "... for loop below is printing more stuff than expected...", but some more detail would be helpful.

Comment: So, @epascarello, if i remove that line, it wont print like the output, but im not very used to DOM to know exactly what is happening. The problem is in the foor loop, because if i remove any of the two lines, it wont work, it will only overwrite the barcode div and print 3 times a text from innerhtml like: [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Just to update, as the innerhtml property returns only string, i've changed it to show an empty space, and when i do that i get a vertical stack of barcodes as intended. Idk if this is the right way but i figured out the words problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set innerHTML property, the value should be the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element. Try to modify your code as below (Since you have added the new items via the innerHtml property, I think there is no need to use the appendChild() method):

```
    if (imprimirQuantidadeTotal == true) {
        for (var i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
            //container.appendChild(etiqueta);
            container.innerHTML += etiqueta.innerHTML;
        }
    }
```

More detail information, check [this sample](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/PozGdwZ). The screenshot as below:

[image]